# How to wire this 4-wire range terminal block with pin style connectors?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding, 240v, range

Could you please help me determine how to properly replace this 4-wire cord that has pin style terminal with a 3-wire cord that has ring style terminals?

[image: original range cord (left) replacement (right)]
terminal block on the range:
[image: terminal block on the range]

old 3-wire cord from a previous range:
[image: old 3-wire cord from a previous range]

Do I need to buy pin style crimps? or should I replace it with a a solid (as opposed to stranded) 3-wire range cord (not sure if it exists)

Outlet/house wiring is aluminum all 3 wires. Are there any concerns of mismatching aluminum/copper?

house wiring:
[image: house wiring]

Range instruction MANUAL below mentions that the cord can be replaced.

> If replacing the power cord, use only a suitable UL or CSA approved one.
>
> - Tighten the power cord using the power cord strain relief bracket supplied with the appliance.
> - Allow enough slack to easily attach the cord terminals to the terminal block

FROM THE INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS PER MANUFACTURER
[image: manual1]

Proper grounding jumper cable was supplied by the manufacturer:
[image]

or FROM THE INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS PER MANUFACTURER HARDWIRED:
[image: hardwired]

NEW (left) cord vs OLD (right):
[image: Original cord (left) vs OLD cord from a previous range(right)]

**Additionally, what is the proper torque value for these flat head terminal blocks?**

I think I found din-pin style connectors being used on original cable but I'm guessing will need a special crimp tool to properly attach and it will be really hard to buy just 2 of them https://www.airic-terminal.com/products_din_terminals_din_pin_terminals.html

But, on the other hand, would i be able to just use a ferrule and $20 crimper?

Comment: This post is hidden. It was deleted 2 days ago by JACK, ThreePhaseEel, BMitch♦.

I think I found din-pin style connectors being used on original cable but I'm guessing will need a special crimp tool to properly attach and it will be really hard to buy just 2 of them https://www.airic-terminal.com/products_din_terminals_din_pin_terminals.html

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert, but to answer my own question, from my research, it looks like I could just use a ferrule, heat shrink ssleeve and a crimper to make similar connection.

On the other hand, according to experts, this is a preferable solution to 4-wire range sockets and retrofitting 3-wire receptacles:
[Is it possible to add a retorfit ground wire to a (3-wire) Type SE, Style U cable from another branch?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/248564/is-it-possible-to-add-a-retorfit-ground-wire-to-a-3-wire-type-se-style-u-cabl)